# How do I output JSON columns in jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, coldfusion, jquery-ui-tooltip

I'm using the qTip jQuery plugin to create dynamic tool tips. The tooltip sends an id to a cfc which runs a query and returns data in JSON format.

At the moment, the tooltip loads with the following:

```
{"COLUMNS:" ["BOOKNAME","BOOKDESCRIPTION"["MYBOOK","MYDESC"]]}
```

Here's the jQuery

```
$('#catalog a[href]').each(function()
{
    var gi = parseInt($(this).attr("href").split("=")[1])
    $(this).qtip(
    {
        content: {
            url: 'cfcs/viewbooks.cfc?method=bookDetails',
            data: { bookID: gi  },
            method: 'get',
            title: {
                text: $(this).text(),
                button: 'Close'
            }
        },
        api :{
        onContentLoad : function(){
            }
        },
    });
});
```

As I mentioned, the data is returned successfully, but I am unsure how to output it and format it with HTML.

I tried adding `content: '<p>' + data.BOOKNAME` + '

' to api `:{ onContentLoad : function(){ .....` to see if I could get it to output something, but I get a 'data is undefined error'

What is the correct way to try and output this data with HTML formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be another case where the ColdFusion debugger, when request debugging output is turned on, causes an ajax error. This is one big "gotcha" we need to remember when working with ColdFusion with debugging enabled. It breaks down ajax.

Answer (score 2):

From the [qTip forums](http://craigsworks.com/projects/forums/thread-solved-too-much-recursion), it appears that the author is adding an ajax call inside the api callback. Maybe that will solve your problem?

Here is his example:

```
$(this).qtip({
 content: 'Loading...',
 api: {
  onRender: function()
  {
   // Setup your AJAX request here
   $.ajax({
    url: DOC_ROOT + "admin/ajax/tooltip_process.php",
    type: 'GET';
    contentType: "application/json charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(json) {
     if(json[0].result == 'success') return json[0].tip;
     else alert('^$%#$#$');
    }
   });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks fudgey. I tried this snipped. The AJAX is firing, but the tooltip simply displays 'Loading.' The JSON data is not being output into the tooltip, or the tooltip is not updating itself after making the call...

Comment: Maybe try reversing the process? Call to Ajax first to build the tooltip contents, then call qTip with the result?... sorry I haven't used qTip that much.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the dataType as json in your request. It tells jquery to treat the response as json, so that you can use it as you are using currently. Also once you get the data as son you can create HTML to display.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but where do I specify the datatype? My CFC is already set to return data as "JSON". I'm a complete novice to jQuery and JS? I'm unsure of the syntax, and where/how to output this stuff!